# product image not coming while sharing the url on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share some urls on facebook page which reads meta tags for facebook for image,title,description.But when i debug that url in debug tool for facebook,it works fine.But when i put the same url in facebook post textbox it doesnot show the image but it shows description and title there.Well thats quite weird behaviour.Its working in debugger tool but not in fb page.
Please suggest something to take care of.

Comment: There' currently an open bug regarding this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/891860967491243/

Comment: They are fixing this issue this coming tuesday.is it??